# How to create multiple entities dynamically in google app engine using google data storage(python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wish to implement this:

There should be an entity A with column 1 having values a,b,c...[dynamically increases by user's input]

There should be another entity B for each values of a , b , c..

How should I approach this problem?
Should I dynamically generate other entities as user creates more [a,b,c,d... ] ?
If yes , how?
Any other way of implementation of the same problem,?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're going for? Right now it's highly unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to dynamically create a new table. You need to redesign your database relation structure.

For example in a user messaging app instead of making a new table for every new message [ which contains `message` and `user name`] , you should rather create a `User table` and `Messages`table separately and implement a `many to one` relation between the two tables.